# Proper way of assigning id in javascript

Tags: javascript

On my page, there are 20 html input elements that have their ids named as idx1, idx2, idx3.....idx20. I am using the following function to iterate through 20 items to get their value. This may not be the optimal way of doing it. Obviously, it is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` error. The way I am assigning the id is wrong. What is the right way to do it?

```
function chkit(){
    var rs = "idx";
    for (c=1; c<21; c++) {
        rs += c;
        var an = document.getElementById(rs).value;
        return an;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use IDs for something like that - assign all `input`s in question a common class name instead.

Comment: you should initialize c inside your function chkit. So it doesn't pollute the global scope. Also chkit is bad naming, what does ch stands for? in the future another dev will have a hard time understanding what ch is.

Comment: also, `return an;` makes the function iterate only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to re-initialize `var rs` to `idx` as `var rs = "idx";` inside your `for` loop. So, change your code from

```
function chkit(){
  var rs = "idx";
  for (c=1; c<21; c++) {
    rs += c;
    var an = document.getElementById(rs).value;
    return an;
  }
}
```

to

```
function chkit(c){
    var rs = "idx" + c;
    var an = document.getElementById(rs).value;
    return an;
}
for (c=1; c<21; c++) {
   var value = chkit(c);
   console.log(value);
}
```

Now the `for` loop will call the function `chkit()` so that it does not return from first iteration as in your `for` loop. Using that will always set the value of `rs` to `"idx" + c` to make it `idx1`, `idx2`, `idx3` and so on. Using these values the code, `document.getElementById(rs).value;` will work properly and you won't get that error.

Comment: Why do the double append. Why not just `var rs = "idx" + c;`?

Comment: @Jamiec nice one. Accepted your suggestion

Comment: You might also want to point out that the `return an;` inside the loop makes this function return after the first iteration.